# Grafico google Analytics em dashboard administrativo

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou quebrando a cabeça para puxar alguns dados do google analytics e jogar em um dashboard administrativo para que o cliente possa acompanhar os acessos ao seu site.

Já revirei a internet buscando informações mas não consegui fazer funcionar. 
Estou caindo no seguinte erro:

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request,
>   http://site.com.br/painel/oauth2callback.php, does not
>   match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the
>   authorized redirect URIs, visit:
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/135467487641321050540?project=8671114465475470

Porém a url está sim autorizada na credencial que criei para o projeto.
Tentei acessar a URL que apresenta no erro, porém cai na tela de credenciais, mas fala que o client OAuth não existe. Já recriei as credenciais e a conta de acesso umas 20x e nada.

Seguem codigos que estou usando:

index.php

```
<?php
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secretes.json you downloaded from the developer console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/vendor/Proj-5872691347db.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);


// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

  // Get the first view (profile) id for the authorized user.
  $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

  // Get the results from the Core Reporting API and print the results.
  $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
  printResults($results);
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/painel/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


function getFirstProfileId($analytics) {
  // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

  // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
  $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

  if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
    $items = $accounts->getItems();
    $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

    // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
    $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
        ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

    if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
      $items = $properties->getItems();
      $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

      // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
      $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
          ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

      if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $profiles->getItems();

        // Return the first view (profile) ID.
        return $items[0]->getId();

      } else {
        throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
  }
}

function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
  // for the last seven days.
  return $analytics->data_ga->get(
      'ga:' . $profileId,
      '7daysAgo',
      'today',
      'ga:sessions');
}

function printResults($results) {
  // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
  // the profile name and total sessions.
  if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

    // Get the profile name.
    $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

    // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
    $rows = $results->getRows();
    $sessions = $rows[0][0];

    // Print the results.
    print "<p>First view (profile) found: $profileName</p>";
    print "<p>Total sessions: $sessions</p>";
  } else {
    print "<p>No results found.</p>";
  }
}

?>
```

oauth2callback.php

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secrets.json you downloaded from the Developers Console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/vendor/Proj-5872691347db.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/painel/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/painel';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>
```

Conto com a ajuda de vocês.
Desde já obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muita luta e pesquisa consegui resolver, caso mais alguém precise fiz da seguinte mandeira:

```
<?php

    // Carrega a biblioteca do Google API PHP.
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

      // Criar uma conta de serviço no Console do Google e baixar o arquivo JSON
      $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/vendor/Aqui-Vem-o-Arquivo.json';

      // Criando e configurando um novo client object.
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
      $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
      $client->setAccessType('offline');
      $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
      $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
      $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
      $token = $client->getAccessToken();
      $accessToken = $token['access_token'];


    ?>
```

Script que gera os gráficos

```
<script>
        (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
          g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
          js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
          fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
        }(window,document,'script'));
        </script>
<script>

    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

      /**
       * Obtem token de acesso do lado do servidor.
       */
      gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        'serverAuth': {
          'access_token': '<?php echo $accessToken?>'
        }
      });


      /**
       * Cria gráfico com visitas (sessions e usuários)
      **/
      var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        query: {
          'ids': 'ga:3215454654', // <-- Replace with the ids value for your view.
          'start-date': '30daysAgo',
          'end-date': 'yesterday',
          'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:users',
          'dimensions': 'ga:date'
        },
        chart: {
          'container': 'chart-1-container',
          'type': 'LINE',
          'options': {
            'width': '100%'
          }
        }
      });
      dataChart1.execute();


      /**
       * Cria gráfico com páginas mais acessadas
      **/
      var dataChart2 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        query: {
          'ids': 'ga:3215454654', //  <-- Trocar aqui pelo ID da vista da propriedade.
          'start-date': '30daysAgo',
          'end-date': 'yesterday',
          'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
          'dimensions': 'ga:pagePathLevel1',
          'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
          'filters': 'ga:pagePathLevel1!=/',
          'max-results': 7
        },
        chart: {
          'container': 'chart-2-container',
          'type': 'PIE',
          'options': {
            'width': '100%',
            'pieHole': 4/9,
          }
        }
      });
      dataChart2.execute();


      /**
       * Cria gráfico com cidades que mais visitaram
      **/

      var dataChart3 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        query: {
          'ids': 'ga:3215454654', // <-- Trocar aqui pelo ID da vista da propriedade.
          'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
          'dimensions': 'ga:city',
          'start-date': '30daysAgo',
          'end-date': 'yesterday',
          'max-results': 6,
          'sort': '-ga:sessions'


        },
        chart: {
          'container': 'chart-3-container',
          'type': 'PIE',
          'options': {
            'width': '100%',
            'pieHole': 4/9,
          }
        }
      });
      dataChart3.execute();

    });
    </script>
```